# How to get a message sent from View Model using a sealed class?

Tags: kotlin, subclass, android-mvvm, sealed-class, kotlin-sealed

I have an app that uses Kotlin with an MVVM approach. My goal here is to send the state (SUCCESS, FAIL, ERROR, EXCEPTION.VM_INSERT...) from View Model to activity. In my activity, I observe the state and based on that I will inform the user about the state. The SUCCESS, FAIL, ERROR state works as expected, unfortunately, I struggle to find out how show in Activity the exception message send by EXCEPTION.VM_INSERT.

ViewModel State:

```
sealed class ViewModelState {

    sealed class EXCEPTION : ViewModelState() {
        class VM_INSERT(val exception: String) : ViewModelState()
        class VM_UPDATE(val exception: String) : ViewModelState()
        class VM_DELETE(val exception: String) : ViewModelState()
        class VM_QUERY(val exception: String) : ViewModelState()
    }
    
    object SUCCESS : ViewModelState()
    object FAIL : ViewModelState()
    object ERROR : ViewModelState()

}
```

ViewModel:

```
...
    private val _insertWordStatus = MutableLiveData<ViewModelState>()
    val insertWordStatus: LiveData<ViewModelState> = _insertWordStatus

    fun insertWord(word: Word) = viewModelScope.launch {

        try {
            val insertedRowId = repository.insertWord(word)

            if (insertedRowId > -1) {
                _insertWordStatus.value = ViewModelState.SUCCESS
            } else {
                _insertWordStatus.value = ViewModelState.FAIL
            }

        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            _insertWordStatus.value = ViewModelState.ERROR
            _insertWordStatus.value =
                ex.localizedMessage.toString()?.let { ViewModelState.EXCEPTION.VM_INSERT(it) }

        }
...
```

Activity:

```
...
        wordViewModel.insertWordStatus.observe(this, Observer { viewModelState ->

            if (viewModelState == ViewModelState.SUCCESS ) {

            } else if (viewModelState == ViewModelState.FAIL) {

            } else if (viewModelState == ViewModelState.ERROR) {

            } else {

            }

        })
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to make all the intended children of `EXCEPTION` subclasses of `EXCEPTION`. Also, you should move their shared property into the superclass so you take advantage of inheritance to, for example, log the error without having to check the specific type of EXCEPTION.

```
sealed class EXCEPTION(val exception: String) : ViewModelState() {
    class VM_INSERT(exception: String) : EXCEPTION(exception)
    class VM_UPDATE(exception: String) : EXCEPTION(exception)
    class VM_DELETE(exception: String) : EXCEPTION(exception)
    class VM_QUERY(exception: String) : EXCEPTION(exception)
}
```

In my opinion, you should refactor it as follows. I don't think the complexity of a sealed class is justified if every one of its children has identical class structure. That's really fighting against the basic principles of object oriented programming. Example:

```
class EXCEPTION(val exception: String, val type: EXCEPTION.Type) : ViewModelState() {
    enum class Type { VM_INSERT, VM_UPDATE, VM_DELETE, VM_QUERY }
}
```

By the way, you should look up how to use `when` statements in Kotlin. It is much cleaner than a chain of `else if`s when they're all checking against the same argument. Example:

```
wordViewModel.insertWordStatus.observe(this) { viewModelState ->

    when(viewModelState) {
        ViewModelState.SUCCESS - > {

        } 
        ViewModelState.FAIL -> {

        } 
        ViewModelState.ERROR -> {

        } 
        ViewModelState.EXCEPTION -> {

        } 
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to use the second suggested with the enum class approach and I added to my view model this:
_insertWordStatus.value = ViewModelState.EXCEPTION("My Test Exception",ViewModelState.EXCEPTION.Type.VM_INSERT)

Then in the activity, I use 
ViewModelState.EXCEPTION -> {
, but I having and error message:
Classifier 'EXCEPTION' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here.

Secondly, how to get access to the inserted message "My Test Exception" in the activity ?

Comment: I found the issue.

1, I have to add import to my activity
....internal.state.message.viewmodel.ViewModelState.EXCEPTION

2, in "when" statement I am using  the "is"

is EXCEPTION -> {
    val exceptionTypeName = viewModelState.type.name
    val exceptionMessage = viewModelState.exception
}